# Extract all submatrix of size r from a given matrix Julia

Tags: algorithm, matrix, julia

I want to extract all submatrices of size **k*l** from a given matrix M.
here is my code

```
function submatrices(arr, k, l)
    n, m = size(arr) # Get size of input matrix
    for i in 1:(n-k+1)
        for j in 1:(m-l+1)
            for p in 0:(k-1)
                for q in 0:(l-1)
                    print(arr[i+p, j+q], " ")
                end
                println()
            end
            println("*****************")
        end
    end
end
```

```
Let A = [1 2 3; 
         4 5 6;
         7 8 9]
l=k=r = 2
submats = submatrices(A, r,r)
```

I am getting

```
1 2
4 5
*****************
2 3
5 6
*****************
4 5
7 8
*****************
5 6
8 9
*****************
```

I want to get all submatrices of size 2*2 from A

```
1 2
4 5
*****************
1 2
7 8
*****************
1 3
4 6
*****************
1 3
7 9
*****************
2 3
5 6
*****************
2 3
8 9
*****************
4 5
7 8
*****************
4 6
7 9
*****************
5 6
8 9
*****************
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
julia> using IterTools

julia> submatrices(A, k, l) = [A[s,t] 
  for s in subsets(axes(A,1),k), 
      t in subsets(axes(A,2),l)]
submatrices (generic function with 1 method)

julia> submatrices(A,2,2)
3×3 Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2; 4 5]  [1 3; 4 6]  [2 3; 5 6]
 [1 2; 7 8]  [1 3; 7 9]  [2 3; 8 9]
 [4 5; 7 8]  [4 6; 7 9]  [5 6; 8 9]
```

This function can be used to generate output like in the question:

```
julia> foreach(x->(display(x); println("****")), submatrices(A,2,2))
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 4  5
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 7  8
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  5
 7  8
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3
 4  6
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3
 7  9
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  6
 7  9
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  3
 5  6
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  3
 8  9
****
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 5  6
 8  9
****
```